# Using double interrogation mark sentences with three option in objective c syntax what is that meaning?

Tags: objective-c, syntax, operator-keyword

I downloaded a project in Github ,and see documents that have a expression I can't understand it.
Previous, I saw one question sentence with two option and understand expression,but the documents using two question sentence with three option in expression I can't understand it how it to operate.

```
{CGSize contentSize = CGSizeMake(direction == PRSlideViewDirectionHorizontal ? infiniteScrollingEnabled ? width * numberOfPages * 512 : width * numberOfPages : width,
                                        direction == PRSlideViewDirectionVertical ? infiniteScrollingEnabled ? height * numberOfPages * 512 : height * numberOfPages : height);}
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess you're confused by the `a ? b ? c : d : e` construct, aren't you? It's the so-called *ternary operator* used twice (very bad style). Let's break it down:

- `x ? y : z` means: *If `x` evaluates to true, use the expression `y` otherwise use `z`*.
- `a ? b ? c : d : e` parses as: `a ? (b ? c : d) : e`. So if `a` is true, then `b` is evaluated. If that is true, `c` is used, otherwise `d`. If `a` was false, `e` is used.

So, what can `direction == PRSlideViewDirectionHorizontal ? infiniteScrollingEnabled ? width * numberOfPages * 512 : width * numberOfPages : width` evaluate to?

- `direction == PRSlideViewDirectionHorizontal` is true, `infiniteScrollingEnabled` is true: use `width * numberOfPages * 512`
- `direction == PRSlideViewDirectionHorizontal` is true, `infiniteScrollingEnabled` is false: use `width * numberOfPages`
- `direction == PRSlideViewDirectionHorizontal` is false: use `width`

Since this is hard to parse for humans I would avoid these constructs and go for a temporary variable and two simple `if`'s instead.

```
CGFloat tmp;
if (direction == PRSlideViewDirectionHorizontal) {
    if (infiniteScrollingEnabled) {
        tmp = width * numberOfPages * 512;
    } else {
        tmp = width * numberOfPages;
    }
} else {
    tmp = width;
}
```